# Batch file get result into runtime variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The following code is ment to get Chrome current version into a runtime variable. What am I missing here?

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value') do set VAR=%%i
echo %VAR%
pause
```

The result :

```
    C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe - Invalid alias
 verb.
```

Comment: Are you sure that double backslashes are required here?

Comment: Dunno, they are not breaking the script either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting gets a little different when inside a FOR command.  Need the nested FOR to get rid of the empty lines.

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'" get Version /value ') do (
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do set var=%%H
)
echo %var%
pause
```